# Calculate cost of clustering in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, distributed-computing, k-means

I have a  data frame of million records and I have used `pyspark` `ml` .

KMeans to identify clusters , Now I want to find the within set sum of squares error((WSSSE) for the number of clusters that I have used.

my spark version is 1.6.0 and  computeCost is not available in pyspark ml till spark 2.0.0 ,So I have to make it on my own .

I have used this method to find squared error but its taking long time to give me the output .I am looking for a better way to find WSSSE.

```
check_error_rdd = clustered_train_df.select(col("C5"),col("prediction"))

c_center = cluster_model.stages[6].clusterCenters()
check_error_rdd = check_error_rdd.rdd
print math.sqrt(check_error_rdd.map(lambda row:(row.C5- c_center[row.prediction])**2).reduce(lambda x,y: x+y) )
```

`clustered_train_df` is my original training data  after fitting a ML PIPELINE,`C5` is the `featuresCol` in `KMeans`.

`check_error_rdd` looks like below:

```
check_error_rdd.take(2)
Out[13]: 
[Row(C5=SparseVector(18046, {2398: 1.0, 17923: 1.0, 18041: 1.0, 18045: 0.19}), prediction=0),
 Row(C5=SparseVector(18046, {1699: 1.0, 17923: 1.0, 18024: 1.0, 18045: 0.91}), prediction=0)]
```

`c_center` is the list of cluster centres where every centre is a list of length 18046:

```
print len(c_center[1]) 
18046
```

Comment: It appears to me from the many values of 1.0 and the enormous number of zeros in your sparse vectors, that your data are primarily indicator variables.  There are a number of problems the KMeans algorithm will have with such data.  One workaround is to use Principal Components Analysis (PCA) or some other factorization/dimensionality reduction technique before clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have computed the [cost of k-means prior to version 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216760/compute-cost-of-kmeans).

As for the "slow"-ness you are mentioning: For 100m points, with 8192 centroids, it took me 50 minutes to compute the cost, with 64 executors and 202092 partitions, with 8G memory and 6 cores for every machine, in client mode.

---

Quoting the [ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel.computeCost):

> computeCost(rdd)
>
> Return the K-means cost (sum of squared
> distances of points to their nearest center) for this model on the
> given data.
>
> Parameters:   rdd – The RDD of points to compute the cost on.
>
> New in version ***1.4.0***.

If you somehow failing to use this because you have a DataFrame, just read: [How to convert a DataFrame back to normal RDD in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000514/how-to-convert-a-dataframe-back-to-normal-rdd-in-pyspark)

---

As for your approach, I don't see anything bad with just a glance.

Comment: I will check this one out . Thanks

Comment: Edit queue is full. The hyperlinked ref link is old. Here's new one - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel.computeCost